# How to pass parameter to method call in Struts 2 OGNL

Tags: java, struts2, ognl

I want to use a property as a param of an object's method.

```
<s:property value="orderProductId" />
```

returns correct value (e.g. 1)

```
<s:iterator value="%{order.getProductById(1).activations}">
```

gives me correct value too. But

```
<s:iterator value="%{order.getProductById(#orderProductId).activations}">
```

doesn't. Not sure why #orderProductId doesn't interpret correctly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ah, the joy of %#$ in OGNL...
This doesn't work ?

```
<s:iterator value="%{order.getProductById(orderProductId).activations}">
```

Comment: I want to do something similar, but to static method call and above solution doesn't work.

Comment: Worked perfectly well ! Adding my code snippet so its useful for others too `code`           <s:iterator value="%{getComments(mid)}">
 <div class="col"> 
  <b>User :</b> <s:property value="content" />
 </div>
 <div class="col">
 <s:property value="user.username" />
      </div>          </s:iterator>`code`