# OGNL Syntax Issue

Tags: java, jsp, syntax, struts2, ognl

I have a Struts 2 JSP page with the following snippet:

```
<s:property value="%{myVariable}" />
```

which correctly prints out the value of `myVariable`.

Now, I want to pass `myVariable` to a method in my action that computes a result based on the value of `myVariable`. I tried the following:

```
<s:property value="%{myMethod(myVariable)}" />
```

The first line in `myMethod` prints out a debug statement. With the above snippet, this debug statement was not printed.

I then tried this:

```
<s:property value="%{myMethod(#myVariable)}" />
```

My debug statement printed, but the value of `myVariable` was passed as null even though it has a value when it is printed via `<s:property value="%{myVariable}" />`

What is the correct syntax for passing a page variable to a Struts 2 method?

Comment: Please post your jsp file.

Comment: If this is not working that's strange. I've seen some strange things if you've used a custom tags. That aside, you should be able to use s:set to assign the variable to a new name and change the scope from page to action. You could also try to to force the scope #attr.myVariable (will search page scope first)

Comment: Which type is your `myVariable` and what type takes your method?

Comment: @AleksandrM - The actual type of myVariable is a complex data type from my application, but I've tested with a String variable and encountered the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<s:property value="%{myMethod(myVariable)}" />
```

is a correct syntax, but to get the value of the method that have a signature

```
public String myMethod(String value){
  return value;
}
```

required the getter for `myVariable`

```
public String getMyVariable() {
  return myVariable;
}
```

if you set the value to `myVariable` like

```
private String myVariable = "myValue";
```

then it should be printed in JSP. If the argument is other type it will be converted to `String` and the method will call.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing target object, ex

```
<s:property value="%{myTarget.myMethod(myVariable)}" />
```

More: [How to pass parameter to method call in Struts 2 OGNL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945684/how-to-pass-parameter-to-method-call-in-struts-2-ognl)

Comment: The method that I'm trying to call is inside my Action. It isn't a property of the myVariable object. In my action, I have execute() and a myMethod(String parameter) method.

Comment: So I'm not particularly sure what you mean by myTarget. Is that the fully qualified path to my struts action (i.e. - com.web.actions.ViewDataAction)?